# Where is the documentation on all built-in Maven expressions?

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

When building a Maven plugin, where can I find documentation for the built-in expressions that can be used for @parameter expression="${...}" constructs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the [Maven Properties Guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+Properties+Guide). Check also the chapter [9.2. Maven Properties](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html) of *Maven: The Complete Reference*.

Comment: Thanks. Additionally, http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Mojo+Developer+Cookbook is very helpful.

Comment: The first link died. I can't seem to access the second one too.

Comment: Links in your answer are dead

Answer (score 6):

You might also try the [help:evaluate](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/evaluate-mojo.html) goal of the [maven help plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/) to quickly show the values of one of these properties from the command line. For example

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.build.outputDirectory
```

would echo the output directory of the current project.

Comment: I know that it's very helpful if you know what property you are looking for, but it's no help in determining what properties there are.

Comment: Just FYI, 
`mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression='project.properties'`  
lists properties declared in your project.